# How to keep image position despite window/device size?

Tags: html, css, centering

**Here's the scenario.**

---

I have 2 images, a `background-image` for a `div` and a regular image inside a div. My question is, how would I get each image to be in the exact position of eachother even on different window size/device? Here's an image depicting what I want.

[image]

Any help will be truly appreciated. My skills for HTML and CSS are not the greatest.
Here's my code:

```
.located {
  background: url(images/located.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 25%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
}
.userimage {
  margin-left: 46%;
  top: 20%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="located"></div>

<div class="userimage">
    <?php echo $userSkin3D;?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="located">
  <div class="userimage">
      <?php echo $userSkin3D;?>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.located {
  background: url(images/located.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 25%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
}

.userimage {
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    position: inherit;
}
```